# Быстрые ссылки

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы

Добрый день, форумчане! Мне интересно кто-нибудь знает как достигается такая шутка, что в поисковиках от сайта помимо основной ссылки подсвечиваются дополнительные ссылки, иконки, картинки, адреса, телефоны и карты? Вот прикладываю скрин поисковика Яндекса:
[image]

Что для этого надо сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@IntegralAL](/users/3549/integralal)](/users/3549/integralal), научитесь уже пользоваться поиском...

По запросу "yandex быстрые ссылки" моментально ищется нужный вам гайд.

**[Быстрые ссылки - Яндекс.Помощь: Директ](http://help.yandex.ru/direct/?id=1112552)**

---

Если нужно бесплатно:

**[Семантическая разметка страниц](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/schema-org/what-is-schema-org.xml)**
**[Какие данные можно передать](http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/site-content/data-transmit.xml)**
**[Валидатор семантической разметки](http://webmaster.yandex.ru/microtest.xml)**

Comment: @VenZell, это платная услуга в директе, которая предназначена для контекстной рекламы. http://direct.yandex.ru А что касается обычных сайтов в поиске где им такое делать? Читал что роботы поисковые сами как-то отбирают ссылки и тексты и вносят их под основной ссылкой сайта.

Comment: @IntegralAL, информация об этом тоже содержится в разделе помощи Яндекса.  
Добавил основные ссылки в ответ.